# Is it possible to create controls in a separate thread that can be returned to the UI thread for use?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, multithreading

My project sets the content of TabItems based on the content of a provided XML file. The XML file is read and content is added to the TabItem, which may include TextBlocks, Borders, Buttons, OxyPlots, and so on.

This may take a noticeable amount of time depending on the size and complexity of the XML file. Optimally, I'd like to build the content of the TabItem in a separate thread then return it to the UI thread to display.

The problem is that the thread that created the controls owns them and I am unable to use them on the UI thread.

Is there any way to change thread ownership of controls?

Comment: You can't. Only `Freezable` types can be passed between threads when in a frozen state. Common controls don't derive from  `Freezable`. You could process the XML file asynchronously and use data virtualization when applicable. Controls like `ListView` also offer UI virtualization. In general data handling can be moved to a background thread but UI belongs to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

The controls themselves need to be created on the main thread, but you can always control the rate at which they're created in a seperate thread (or rather, task). Here's a view model that creates colors at a deliberately-slow rate:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Color> Colors { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Color>();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            foreach (var color in ColorStructToList())
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Colors.Add(color));
            }
        });

    }

    // courtesy https://stackoverflow.com/a/16130999/1177147
    public static List<Color> ColorStructToList()
    {
        return typeof(Colors).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public)
                            .Select(c => (Color)c.GetValue(null, null))
                            .ToList();
    }

}
```

And here's an ItemsControl that will create items to display those as they're being created, and without tying up the main GUI thread:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Margin="2" >
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```